# Export data into excel using maatwebsite/excel did not retain the spacing or margin in front of each data cell | Laravel | maatwebsite-excel

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am working on a Laravel application where I am using "maatwebsite/excel" package to export the data into the excel format. The application has multilevel data, so I use a view and export the excel [from the view](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html). The data is exported successfully.

The problem with the margin and spacing which I added in front of each data(based on level).

[image: HTML view of the data]

As you can see this image is the HTML view of the data. I add space in front of each account name at each level.

So I want to export the excel in the same format. But when I export it into excel it does not retain the spacing and convert it into one space.

[image: Data in excel form]

I tried `&emsp; &nbsp;` and also `padding-left` style but it doesn't work at all.

**Code Section**

***ChartOfAccountsExport.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\UserAccountingHead;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnWidths;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use Auth;

class ChartOfAccountsExport implements FromView, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnWidths, WithStyles
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function columnWidths(): array
    {
        return [
            'B' => 55,            
        ];
    }

    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
            // Style the first row as bold text.
            1    => ['font' => ['bold' => true]],

            // Styling an entire column.
            'A'  => ['font' => ['size' => 16]],
            'B'  => ['font' => ['size' => 16]],
            'C'  => ['font' => ['size' => 16]],
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @return \View
    */
    public function view(): View
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $accounting_heads = $user->company->accountingHeads;
        $parent_accounting_heads = $accounting_heads->whereNull('parent_id')->where('visibility', true);

        return view('accounting.charts-raw', compact('parent_accounting_heads')); 
    }
}
```

***charts-raw.blade.php***

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ __('labels.code') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('labels.account_name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('labels.account_type') }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($parent_accounting_heads as $accounting_head)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $accounting_head->custom_code }}</td>
                <td style="background-color: #0e68b1; color: white; border: 1px solid black;">{{ $accounting_head->name }}</td>
                <td>Control</td>
            </tr>
            @if($accounting_head->where('parent_id', $accounting_head->id))
                @include('includes.charts-raw-children', ['accounting_heads' => $accounting_head->where('parent_id', $accounting_head->id)->get(), 'level' => 1])
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***charts-raw-children.blade.php***

```
@foreach ($accounting_heads as $accounting_head)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $accounting_head->custom_code }}</td>
        <td @if($level == 1) style="background-color: #0e68b1; color: white; border: 1px solid black;" @endif>
            @if($level > 1)
                @for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++)
                    &emsp;
                @endfor
            @endif
            {{ $accounting_head->name }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ $level == 1 ? trans('labels.control'): '' }}</td>
    </tr>
@if($accounting_head->where('parent_id', $accounting_head->id))
    @include('includes.charts-raw-children', ['accounting_heads' => $accounting_head->where('parent_id', $accounting_head->id)->get(), 'level' => $level + 1])
@endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Have you tried using tabs (`"\t"`) ?

Comment: I tried `Regular space: &nbsp;` `Two spaces gap: &ensp;` and `Four spaces gap: &emsp;` but no luck